# new entry deletes previous entry in sql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database in which a user enters a message and it stores in the database. but with every new message from the same user, the new message overwrites the old message. this is the problem. I want to keep all the messages. so how can I do it? I use PHP for connecting to my PHPMyAdmin database.

```
INSERT INTO users SET `message` = "hdfh" ,`budget`="5235" , `media`="ghdh" WHERE username='somen8099' ;
```

there is error on the above line.

Comment: There's no such thing as a PHPMyAdmin database. PHPMyAdmin is, as its name sort of implies, simply an Administration tool, for MySQL, written in PHP.

Comment: this is not the answer sir but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you could be using update instead of insert, also check if the database has any triggers set to delete on new inserts

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `message` = ? ,`budget`=? , `media`=?  WHERE `username`=?";

Comment: this is my code and my users are constants they don't change so insert command shows me error

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you shared some codes, especially the code where you insert data. As i see it there could be 1 problem.

You are not inserting, but rather, updating the same row. In that case you are probably using something like `UPDATE MESSAGES SET Message = ?,User_id = ? WHERE id = ?`

You should be using `INSERT INTO MESSAGES SET Message = ?,User_id = ?`. This answer might be irrelevant with your problem but again, the information provided is limited.

Comment: thanks sir, i use `$sql = "UPDATE users SET message = ? ,budget=? , media=? WHERE username=?"; `
this command in my PHP code but the problem is I want to insert data in a particular row  so I Use WHERE command but it gives me ERROR

````INSERT INTO users SET `message` = "hdfh" ,`budget`="5235" , `media`="ghdh" WHERE username='somen8099' ;````
this code gives me ERROR

Comment: Does it give an error or does it deletes the old message when you want to keep the old message. By the way, when update a column of a row, you are deleting old data and inserting a new data, if you want to keep all the old messages, you should first `SELECT` the old message, code would be something like `SELECT message FROM users WHERE username = ?` , and then put the old message in a variable, and join the old and new message together by doing `$joinedMessage = $oldMessage . ' ' . $newMessage` and then update the column with `$joinedMessage`.

Comment: No, you cant use `INSERT INTO` and `WHERE` together, You should be doing `UPDATE users SET message = $joinedMessage ,budget="5235" , media="ghdh" WHERE username='somen8099'`

Comment: I am using this command and this causes the issue that it overwrites the previous message

Comment: Yes, first you have save your old message to a variable in your code, then you have to save your new message to another variable, then merge them together to a new variable, and finally you can update that column with both previous and new message. Lets do it together; first fetch your old message. `SELECT message FROM users WHERE username = ?`, and put its value to a variable, this is your old message so lets call it $oldMessage. Ok so we have our old message now, then put your new message to another variable called `$newMessage`.

Comment: Then merge them together by doing this, `$mergedMessage = $oldMessage . ' ' . $newMessage;`, Finally you are set to update your row by doing `UPDATE users SET message = $mergedMessage ,budget="5235" , media="ghdh" WHERE username='somen8099'`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: i made another table for storing all previous data then I use INNER JOIN keyword to get all the data from new and previous table data. but there is an issue, INNER JOIN  marge two tables columns side by side this is annoying I post a question lets see anyone can solve you are requested to see the question.